# TSQL BINARY_CHECKSUM as a default value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

There is a column in a table, which should store Checksum for list of columns, but I'd like to create it as a default value for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE tblVitalyTest (id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), startTime DATETIME, value1 INT, value2 INT, value3 INT, value4 DATETIME, BinCheckSum BIGINT)
GO
ALTER TABLE tblVitalyTest ADD  DEFAULT (BINARY_CHECKSUM(value1, value2, value3, value4)) FOR [BinCheckSum]
GO
```

So, it should be used like that:

```
INSERT INTO tblVitalyTest (startTime,value1,value2,value3,value4) VALUES ('2015-05-25',1,1,1,'2015-11-11')
```

As a result it should be something like that:

> id, startTime, value1, value2, value3, value4, BinCheckSum
>
> 1, "2015-05-25", 1, 1, 1, "2015-11-11", **46173**

But table "default" table creation fails unfortunately.

There is a query to play around:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), startTime DATETIME, value1 INT, value2 INT, value3 INT, value4 DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @a (startTime,value1,value2,value3,value4) 
    VALUES ('2015-05-25 08:00',1,1,1,'2015-11-11'),('2015-05-25 09:00',1,2,1,'2015-11-11')
          ,('2015-05-25 10:00',null,null,null,'2015-11-11'),('2015-05-25 11:00',2,1,1,'2015-11-11'),('2015-05-25 11:00',null,null,null,'2015-11-12')

SELECT a.*,BINARY_CHECKSUM(a.value1,a.value2,a.value3,a.value4) [BinCheckSum]
FROM @a a
```

Please let me know is there any way to create a Binary_Checksum as a default value for the column?

Comment: Perhaps you would be better off creating an `INSERT`/`UPDATE` trigger to calculate the checksum whenever a row is inserted or updated. As documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx), only constant values may be used as column defaults. (Something makes me feel that you're trying to do something peculiar here. You might want to look at [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you can't. But you can do something similar with a trigger. See below

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tblVitalyTestUpdateInsertTrigger ON dbo.tblVitalyTest
  AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
  BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE
      vt
    SET
      vt.BinCheckSum = BINARY_CHECKSUM(vt.value1, vt.value2, vt.value3,
                                       vt.value4)
    FROM
      dbo.tblVitalyTest vt
      INNER JOIN INSERTED i
        ON vt.id = i.id

  END
GO
```

Comment: I think this one will work slower on insert, but much faster on select. I go with this solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can create the column as a computed column. Try this

```
CREATE TABLE tblVitalyTest
 (id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     startTime DATETIME, 
     value1 INT,
     value2 INT,
     value3 INT, 
     value4 DATETIME, 
     cksum AS BINARY_CHECKSUM(value1,value2, value3, value4 ))
    GO
```

Or you can ALTER and existing table as such

```
ALTER TABLE tblVitalyTest
ADD cksum AS BINARY_CHECKSUM(value1, value2, value3, value4);
GO
```

Results of this query (based on your INSERT example):

```
      select id, cksum
      from tblVitalyTest
```

would be:

```
   id   cksum
    1   46173
    2   46941
    3   -44486
    4   33885
    5   -44487
```

Comment: It's a good idea, thank you, but I'll go with trigger solution, i.e. computed columns works well for small tables, but if I have billion rows and about 25 value-columns - it can be really slow.
Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

**Post SQL Server 2005**

Rather than creating a trigger, a cleaner solution is to create a [**persisted** computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16).

Adding to BICube's response, the CREATE TABLE statement is:

```
CREATE TABLE tblVitalyTest
 (id BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1), 
     startTime DATETIME, 
     value1 INT,
     value2 INT,
     value3 INT, 
     value4 DATETIME, 
     cksum AS BINARY_CHECKSUM(value1,value2,value3,value4) PERSISTED
)
    GO
```

When the computed column is **persisted**, you take the computation hit on insert and update, but every read is free.