# tsql Bind a default value to a formula

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm adding a hash to a small table using checksum.
The hash value must stay, even after changing the source.
Hash code:

```
UPPER( cast(master.sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CHECKSUM([CompanyName],[City],[Country])) as varchar))
```

If I modify the CompanyName, I need the hash to stay put. This eliminate a computed column.

> ! [tsql computed column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429601/tsql-binary-checksum-as-a-default-value)
>   
>   Altering `'Column Properties'` → `'Default Value or Binding'`, only add my formula as string by adding the prefix N'.
>   I can use an insert trigger to do it, however, I think should be a better method.

Comment: Why not create a UDF with the code, and once the row gets inserted, you also calculate this `Company Name Hash` and store it? An insert trigger would be fine, what do you have against it? Otherwise, put this logic in the `INSERT` query you write, or the application code that sends this data.

Comment: UDF: will not be 'static', nothing against insert trigger: they are great!.  Insert/code: there are multiple hooks that create a new records not just one, will be a maintenance nightmare